# How to access class variables of a remote object

Tags: java, client-server, rmi

I am currently working on an assignment that deals with RMI. Essentially, it is just a chatroom. The problem that I am running into, though, is that I want to be able to get a username variable from my client, but that variable is not part of its remote interface:

```
public interface MulticastClient extends Remote {

    public void deliver( MulticastClient sender, String channel, 
        Serializable message) throws RemoteException;
}
```

From what I understand, since `sender` is really a remote object, I can only access the methods and variables defined in the interface. Since this is a homework assignment I cannot change the interface (it was given to us).

Some code from my MulticastClient implementation:

```
public class ChatClient implements MulticastClient {

       ...
       private String username;

    @Override
    public void deliver(MulticastClient sender, String channel,
        Serializable message) throws RemoteException {

    String senderName = ((ChatClient)sender).getUsername();
    System.out.println("\r" + senderName + ": " + message.toString());
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    ...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            ...

    ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
    MulticastClient stub = (MulticastClient)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(client, 0);

    Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(hostname, port);
    MulticastService server = (MulticastService)reg.lookup(SERVER_NAME);

            ...
    }
}
```

When I attempt to user the deliver method, as it is now, the error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy0 cannot
be cast to csci4401.mc.ChatClient
```

I know that the cast in `deliver()` is causing the problem, but I am not sure what the correct way to do this is. Is there another way that I can get the ChatClient's username?

Comment: If you need to access a method of the remote object, it really needs to be in the interface.  If you try to hack it with casting, you're ignoring the whole reason for using interfaces.

Comment: Our homework specification says to invoke each instance of chat client with a username from the command line, so that's why I assumed I had to be able to access it somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can access remotely is defined by the remote interface, by definition. What you have at the client isn't the remote object itself, it is a proxy for it that implements the same remote interface. Hence your exception.

Answer (score 0):

What is already said is correct.
If you really need the username and can't change the Interface. There would be the possibility to send the Username in your Message. I don't know if that's possible in your case, as I don't know the Server Implementation nor the Implementation of your Message Class.
This would work if you can freely manipulate the Format of your Message.